# Multi-language vue-laravel project

Tags: localization

I'm developing application with *laravel-vue* , i start donig **localization** and i got confused.
I also tried this:https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-use-laravel-localization-in-vue?page=1&replyId=702589   but it didn't work.

I know how to do it in both laravel and vue i18n but how to use them together?
I have my php files in lang directoey and i install vue i18n, but i can't find a solution to handle this.